# GCP Web Element on Android Browser

Tags: android, browser, mobile, google-cloud-print

I integrated GCP on a project of mine so i can use a mobile/android browser to print. Code that i used is similar to the code below:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/cloudprint/client/cpgadget.js">
</script>
<script defer="defer">
var gadget = new cloudprint.Gadget();
gadget.setPrintButton(cloudprint.Gadget.createDefaultPrintButton("print_button_container"));
gadget.setPrintDocument("url", "[document title]", "[document URL]");
</script>
```

I got this from http://code.google.com/apis/cloudprint/docs/gadget.html

Now when i open it on an android i just see a white box and do not see any printing options. But on a computer I see that it should show me some options for printing. Is there a work around on mobile browsers or i need to change something on the code to work.

Here is a live link you for testing
http://www.google.com/webelements/#!/cloudprint <- click on Print after "Preview"

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but you want to follow this: https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android